# in latex, how to insert footnote on the first use of \acrshort command?

Tags: latex, glossary

the footnote inserted for each `\acrshort{gcd}` but what expected is to insert the footnote on the first use of the command. like the `\gls{gcd}` command. when the `\gls{gcd}` command is used, the footnote only inserted on the first use of the command.

here is the minimal not working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}

\defglsentryfmt[acronym]{%
  \glsgenentryfmt \ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{\footnote{\glsentrydesc{\glslabel}}}
}

\begin{document}

\acrfull{gcd}\\
\acrshort{gcd} \\
\acrshort{gcd} \\
%\gls{gcd} \\
%\gls{gcd} \\

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

[image: here is the output]

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691295/how-to-insert-footnotes-automatically-with-glossaries-package